# How to fix 'Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.' in laravel boiler templage

Tags: laravel-5, themes, boilerplate

I am going to develop laravel project with boiler template.
I want to have multiple themes.

So, I try to install `shipu/themevel` package. However `composer require shipu/themevel`, this command has error like this. Please help me.

> ```
> Using version ^1.6 for `shipu/themevel
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>     - Can only install one of: hassankhan/config[0.11.2, 0.10.0].
>     - Can only install one of: hassankhan/config[0.10.0, 0.11.2].
>     - Can only install one of: hassankhan/config[0.10.0, 0.11.2].
>     - shipu/themevel v1.6 requires hassankhan/config ^0.10.0 -> satisfiable by hassankhan/config[0.10.0].
>     - Installation request for shipu/themevel ^1.6 -> satisfiable by shipu/themevel[v1.6].
>     - Installation request for hassankhan/config (locked at 0.11.2) -> satisfiable by hassankhan/config[0.11.2].
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the higher version of `shipu/themevel`. please update `v2.1` or higher.